# Wix custom action on SQL file - sql component not installed yet

Tags: wix, components, sequence, custom-action

I try to change sql file just before i run it as schema file to my sql component.
the problem is that the file doesn't exist yet(running if(File.Exist()).
can i make dependency of running the custom action when sql binary file already exist, and just before sql creation running.
this is the code:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension">
```

```
    <Binary Id="SqlScriptSQLAuthentication"  SourceFile="..\SQL\CreateSchema.sql" />
    <Binary Id="SqlScriptIntegratedAuthentication"  SourceFile="..\SQL\CreateSchema.sql" />

    <CustomAction Id="ChangeSqlScript"
          BinaryKey="Installer.CA"
          DllEntry="ChangeSqlScript"
          Execute="immediate"
          Return="check" 
          Impersonate='yes'/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>          
      <Custom Action="ChangeSqlScript" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed AND VersionNT</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ROOTFOLDER">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="!(loc.ProductNameFolder)">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Component Id='SqlComponent.SQLAuthentication' Guid='665D641C-3570-4b96-9CA5-2B4C12594A35' KeyPath='yes'>
        <Condition><![CDATA[USEINTEGRATEDSECURITY<>1]]></Condition>
        <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase.SQLAuthentication' Database='[DATABASE_NAME]' User='SQLUser' Server='[DATABASE_SERVER]' CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='no' ContinueOnError='no' />
        <sql:SqlScript Id='SqlScriptSQLAuthentication' BinaryKey='SqlScriptSQLAuthentication' SqlDb='SqlDatabase.SQLAuthentication' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
      </Component>
      <Component Id='SqlComponent.IntegratedAuthentication' Guid='E5DF48AE-2338-4029-9FDF-8DAA6AD0216D' KeyPath='yes'>
        <Condition>USEINTEGRATEDSECURITY = 1</Condition>
        <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase.IntegratedAuthentication' Database='[DATABASE_NAME]' Server='[DATABASE_SERVER]' CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='no' ContinueOnError='no' />
        <sql:SqlScript Id='SqlScriptIntegratedAuthentication' BinaryKey='SqlScriptIntegratedAuthentication' SqlDb='SqlDatabase.IntegratedAuthentication' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
      </Component>
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SqlScript](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/sql/sqlscript.html) documentation describes a `Sequence` attribute you can use to explicitly schedule the action:

```
Specifes the order to run the SQL Scripts. It is recommended that rollback 
scripts be scheduled before their complementary execution script. This order 
is also relative across the SqlString element.
```